# HackerEarth challenge Program - Help Captain Gordon - which corner case am I missing?

Tags: algorithm

This is a HackerEarth programming challenge question. Here's [link](http://www.hackerearth.com/mindsweeper_2/algorithm/help-captain-gordon/)

Here's the problem

> A large network of criminals is working under JOKER to destroy and
>   demolish Gotham city. Captain Gordon is quite tensed about what these
>   criminals can do to Gotham city. Fortunately, Batman comes to his
>   rescue and with the help of the Batman, he was able to rescue N
>   hostages that were trapped by the criminals working under JOKER. He
>   makes them stand in a line and each of the N hostage is given id
>   between 1 to N (inclusive) and no 2 hostages have same id. You are a
>   newly hired programmer who is assigned the task of keeping track of
>   the health status of hostages as Captain Gordon heals them by giving
>   them aspirin each time. Initially,health of each hostage is 0. He then
>   performs following action -
>
> • Gives Aspirin of value v to hostages
>   having id between x and y (both inclusive) which increaces their
>   present health by v.
>
> • He asks you to give him the sum of the health
>   of all the hostages having id between x and y (both inclusive) Can you
>   write a program which keeps track of Gordon’s action?
>
> INPUT 1st Line contains N-no. of hostages 2nd line contains M-no. of
>   actions performed by Captain Gordon. The next M lines contain the
>   actions in the form of either “ 1 x y v “ which denotes Action 1 or “
>   2 x y “ which denotes Action 2.
>
> OUTPUT For each action that Captain Gordon does, if Action 1 is
>   carried out, output nothing but if Action 2 is carried out, the
>   program must output the result that Gordon asks for.
>
> CONSTRAINTS
>
> 1) N<=10^5
>
> 2) M<=10^5
>
> 3) 1<=x < y<=N
>
> 4) 0<=v<=100

```
Sample Input
5
6
2 1 5
1 3 4 5
2 2 4
1 1 3 10
1 1 5 5
2 1 5

Sample Output
0
10
65
```

There is a sample input and sample output. Before submitting the answer you can compile your code and test over there. my code passed it. Then you can submit your answer. After submitting the answer your code is tested for various test cases.

Out of the 10 tests, my code passed 6 tests successfully and 4 partially. And the problem is you can't see which tests are there!!

Can someone finds whats wrong with my code or which corner cases I am missing. Here's the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int N, M, i, j, x, y, v, sum, actn, arr[100001] = {0};

    scanf("%d%d", &N, &M);

    for (i = 1; i <= M; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &actn);

        if (actn == 1) {
            scanf("%d%d%d", &x, &y, &v);
            for (j = x; j <= y; j++)
                arr[j] += v;
        } else {
            scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);
            sum = 0;
            for (j = x; j <= y; j++)
                sum += arr[j];
            printf("%d\n", sum);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please put the problem statement in the question itself. This case is particularly inconvenient as it requires logging in to see the problem statement. Also, preferably provide a high-level description / pseudo-code of your approach in addition to, or instead of, the actual code.

Comment: Do you need to validate the input or is it assumed that the input is always valid?

Comment: Is a 32bit int definitely enough to hold the answer for sum?  Perhaps using long long would pass more cases?  (By the way, you are probably meant to do this problem with a Fenwick tree to avoid exceeding the time limit)

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz used long long to hold sum. passed 7 out of 10 tests successfully. will read about Fenwick tree.

Comment: Where can I get some of that aspirin?

Comment: @Chris No need to validate input because Constraints clearly specifies range of inputs

Comment: Since it sounds like you missed the test case of maxing out all the input variables (eg max number of hostages, max number of actions, maxing feeding each action) which I'd have thought was an obvious one perhaps you should tell us what you've tried? Does it cope with zero actions for example?

Comment: @Chris I don't get what you are saying about maxing out. Max values for input variables is specified in constraints. And what should be the output for zero actions? It should NOT produce any output IMO

Comment: If you have 10^5 people and increase their health by 100 every time on 10^5 actions then sum up the health of all the people then you are going to get a total of 10^12 which causes overflow for integers. You are asking about edge cases and you missed one obvious one (in my opinion) so I was mentioning others and just commenting that without knowing what edge case tests you've done its kind of hard to work out what edge cases you might have missed in your testing. AS for what should happen for zero actions then I'd say no output sounds right but I have no idea what yours does without running it

Comment: @Chris Thanks. read my comment at PeterdeRivaz. I did a silly mistake there. replaced 'arr' from 'int' to 'long long' and forgot to do the same for 'sum'. [here's](http://ideone.com/kYiFuH) new code which passes 9 tests. The only test which is fails shows 1.0015 sec which is more than time limit. any other suggestion for that apart from Fenwick tree(Peter de Rivaz suggested)?

Comment: Cool. For what its worth arr should be fine as int because they shouldn't get higher than 100*10^5 = 10^7 which is within the bounds of an int. Doubt that will make a difference to your time. Just a note that you might want to actually look at what the possible ranges are rather than just increase the size of more than you need to. As for optimization I've no ideas. Peter sounds like he knows what he is talking about.

Answer (score 0):

These type of questions, when the input range is 10^5 can be done using the [segment trees](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-set-1-sum-of-given-range/).

The idea is to maintain the sums of all intermediate range values in a tree structure and when a range is queried, simply adding two or three sub ranges gives the answer.